# Control if-else statements inside for loop

Tags: java, if-statement

```
static void merge(int []part1,int []part2,int []array)
{
    int index1=0;
    int index2=0;

    for(int k=0; k<array.length; k++)
    {
        if(index1==part1.length)
        {
            array[k]=part2[index2];
            index2++;
            System.out.println("fourth");
        }
        else if(index2==part2.length)
        {
            array[k]=part1[index1];
            index1++;
            System.out.println("third");
        }
        else if(part1[index1]<part2[index2])
        {
            array[k]=part1[index1];
            index1++;
            System.out.println("second");
        }
        else
        {
            array[k]=part2[index2];
            index2++;
            System.out.println("first");
        }
    }
}
```

The `part1` and `part2` lengths are 4,and the array length is 8. In this condition why is the "second" is the first to print and not the "first"?

The condition is all `false`, that is why the `else` is the first to print?

I am little confused about `else if`.

Comment: What is your indata? Also, give us the complete output of the program

Comment: What values does part1 and part2 hold ? third condition which prints "second" is based on the values.

Comment: Yeah we need to see the data.  Looks like `part1[index1]<part2[index2]` is true but without seeing the data it's impossible to tell

Comment: if "secound" is printed, then are not all conditions false, `part1[index1]<part2[index2]` is true then. why did you think they are all false? did you know the values of the array?

Comment: It depends on the values of part1 and part2. This could be because part1 has smaller values than part2

Comment: The last if-else block is entered only if `part2`'s element at its current index has a smaller value than of `part1`'s. Additionally, a problem arises here on the third if-else block if all elements of either part1 and part2 have been traversed because you may be referencing an index that is already out of bounds

Answer (score 1):

In a if(condition) else if(condition2) else ..., there is no first/second to be executed. Also this is not really java specific. Only the block for which the condition is true will be executed. Here you first have:

if(index1==part1.length)

=> index1 = 0

=> part1.length = 4

So this condition is false.

else if(index2==part2.length)

we have the exact same scenario here, condition is false

else if(part1[index1]<part2[index2])

here unless we know what's in the input arrays, we can't know if it's true of false, but based on your comment this condition is true, hence the code in this block is executed along with System.out.println("second");.

Think of what this code is trying to achieve (we're merging 2 sorted arrays into a third array that will be sorted as well), understand that it is within a loop, and for each loop iteration it is executing a different block depending on the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You print **second** in your third condition, that is, at the first `for` iteration, when the arrays have any elements in them AND `part1[0] < part2[0]`

Answer (score 0):

When you chain `if else` the first block for which the condition is true, gets run, and no other.

```
if(a) {
   x();
} else if(b) {
   y();
} else if(c) {
   z();
}
```

- If a is true, x() is run, and no other methods.
- If a is false and b is true, y() is run, and no other methods.
- if a is false, b is false, c is true, z() is run, and no other methods.

It may help to realise that the above is equivalent to:

```
if(a) {
   x();
} else {
   if(b) {
      y();
   } else {
      if(c) {
         z();
      }
   }
}
```

That is literally how the compiler interprets it; however most human readers find the first version, with fewer braces and less indentation, easier to read.

---

In your code, if "second" is printed, we can be certain that the third condition is true.

The third condition is:

```
 part1[index1]<part2[index2]
```

The first time around the loop, index1 and index2 are both zero, so this block runs when the first element of `part1` is less than the first element of `part2`.

You could confirm this by adding another debugging println above "second":

```
  System.out.println( "part1[" + index1 + "]=" + part1[index1]);
  System.out.println( "part2[" + index2 + "]=" + part2[index2]);  
  System.out.println("second");
```

But note that debugging using println is a bad habit to get into -- learn to use a debugger as soon as practically possible.